# Ranking from max value to 10th value and output its corresponding row in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, rank

I have a Dataframe for crime rates in the state and I want to rank the top 10 suburbs with the most crime rate. At the moment, I can use .rank() but I want to output the suburb's name, not the value of crime

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post part of your data and code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm forced to infer what the data looks like because you haven't provided a sample of the data. But, if the data looks like this...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['NH', 'CA', 'MA', 'FL'], 'crime_rates':[0.5, 1.3, 0.9, 1.1]})
>>> df
   crime_rates state
0          0.5    NH
1          1.3    CA
2          0.9    MA
3          1.1    FL
```

Then simply sorting with `ascending=False` will return the states sorted by crime rates.

```
>>> df.sort_values('crime_rates', ascending=False)
   crime_rates state
1          1.3    CA
3          1.1    FL
2          0.9    MA
0          0.5    NH
```

If this solution doesn't work due to nuances in your data then post the data and I will revise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html#pandas-series-nlargest) with the `keep` argument to determine how ties are handled.

Create dummy data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Suburb':['Suburb No.'+str(i) for i in range(35)],'Crime Rate':np.random.randint(15,45,35)/100})
```

Calculate Top 10 suburbs by Crime rate

```
df.nlargest(10, 'Crime Rate')
```

Output:

```
    Crime Rate        Suburb
22        0.43  Suburb No.22
2         0.41   Suburb No.2
15        0.41  Suburb No.15
20        0.41  Suburb No.20
29        0.41  Suburb No.29
8         0.40   Suburb No.8
30        0.40  Suburb No.30
34        0.37  Suburb No.34
3         0.36   Suburb No.3
9         0.35   Suburb No.9
```